# TypeScript generation from C# using TypeWriter

Tags: typewriter

Was hoping to generate Angular model classes from C# POCOs/DTOs and Angular service classes from C# controller classes because aint nobody got time to bang out all that boilerplate.

Unfortunately my installation of VisualStudio doesn't have T4 templates so I've been looking for alternatives and found the extension TypeWriter http://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/

I created a `tst` file but then what? Nothing happens. How do you get it to *do* something?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have followed the steps in the [Typewriter getting started guide](http://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/pages/getting-started.html) there is probably something wrong with your template. Check your output window under section 'Typewriter'.

If you're still stuck, start with as simple a template as possible and work from there.